# not exact "7.13 The null coalescing operator" in C# 4.0 spec

Tags: c#

in "7.13 The null coalescing operator" of C# 4.0 spec, it says

> Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists **from a to B**, the result type is B.

By my understand, it should be **from A0 to B**(A0 is the underlying type of A if A is a nullable type, or A otherwise).

```
int? a=null;
long b=5;
```

then type for `a??b` is long, because an implicit conversion exists from int(namely A0) to long.

please help confirm whether my view is correct.

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: just request help for confirming whether my view is correct.

Comment: Are you saying you think there is an error in the spec here? Reading that whole section (not just the line you pasted) I don't think so, this seems correct to me.

Comment: no implicit conversion from int? to long. but one from int to long exists. I have found it's "from A0 to B" in C#3.0. it maybe a typo in C#4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C#3.0 it says:

> Otherwise, if an implicit conversion exists from A0 to B, the result
>   type is B.

in my guess, it may be a typo in C#4.0.